# Nextcloud: Groupfolder OCC for advanced permissions

Tags: nextcloud

I would like to implement the following:

I have a "master folder" in which all subfolders are structured down. However, these subfolders are person-related and should only be visible and editable for the authorized persons including the admin -> This also means that those who do not have authorization should not even see the folder.
I was able to implement the whole thing very successfully, without problems, but with a lot of click work on the web interface.

**Now I want to automate the whole thing:**

1. create a user in Nextcloud
2. create a personal subfolder in the "master folder"
3. assign authorization

The first point has already worked without problems -> the new user is created correctly and added to the group accordingly.
The second point also worked, but I create the folders via `mkdir` and then execute the command `occ files:scan --all`. The folder is already visible for all in the "Master Folder".

Now we come to the third and last point:
I absolutely can't figure out how to create the appropriate Manage advanced permissions on command line level.

The whole group should not be able to see the folder, except the selected persons. I can't find any commands to do this without using the web interface...

I really hope that you can help me somehow, otherwise I will soon be busy with clicking only ...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what you try to achieve here, so here are a few answers that I can think of right now:

### Have new users have the same files

If your goal is to have every new user have the same files in their folder, you can just change the files in `/core/skeleton`. When a user is created, these files are copied into their home.

If the files change a lot you can just upload them to your admin account an share them with the group everyone. (Need the app [Everyone Group](https://apps.nextcloud.com/apps/group_everyone) for that) The users then will see the files shared with them in their homedir.

### Have one folder where all users can read everything, but only write to their own folder

For this I would do the following to set it up:

1. Go to `Settings > Group Folders`
2. Add a group folder (let's call it `master` here)
3. Give the groups `everyone` and `admin` permissions to read and write
4. Activate special permissions and give them to the `admin` group.
5. Go to `Files` and enter the new group folder `master`
6. Click on the 'share' Symbol in the top next to the folder name
7. In the right hand panel, go to the share tab
8. At the bottom make sure that:

   - Admin has permissions to read/write/delete everything
   - Everyone only has permissions to read files and is denied everything else
   - These permissions are set without inheritance. (The arrow are a bit grey when inherited and full black when not)

Now you can do the following every time a user is created:

1. Create a folder in master (either as you suggested or sync an empty folder via [nextcloudcmd](https://docs.nextcloud.com/desktop/3.1/nextcloudcmd.html?highlight=nextcloudcmd))
2. Use the `occ groupfolders:permissions` command to set the permissions. [See here for more information](https://github.com/nextcloud/groupfolders#configuring-advanced-permissions-trough-occ)
   The command probably will look something like this:

```
occ groupfolders:permissions <folder_id> --user=<username> <path> -- +read +write +create +delete
```

So if master has the folder_id `1`, the user has the user_id `adam` and you named this folder `adams_dir`:

```
occ groupfolders:permissions 1 --user=adam /adams_dir -- +read +write +create +delete +share
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Required Apps to be installed:

- [Group Folders](https://apps.nextcloud.com/apps/groupfolders)
- [Everyone Group](https://apps.nextcloud.com/apps/group_everyone)